# Zoom in on all subviews in uiscrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

is it possible to zoom in on all objects in a scrollview?  The scrollview is created dynamically and can contain multiple different types of objects (labels, buttons, imageviews)

```
func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
return //all subviews in scrollview
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a view, add all subviews to this view and add the newly created view as a single subview to the scrollview...

Then in the viewForZoomingInScrollView delegate method return the object at Index 0:

```
func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {

return scrollView.subviews[0]

}
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, can you please provide an example?

Comment: Scrollview delegate = self in viewdidload

Comment: Yeah I can convert it

Comment: add view in scrollview then after add all object in view....does not remove return code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92598/discussion-between-maulik-and-sloptonio).

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your question very well, but you can not zoom in if scrollView contain more than one image , Because the images will appear wasteful if used full image .